# Escribir en un archivo en posición concreta en Python

Tags: python

No sé cómo hacer para especificar en qué parte del archivo quiero escribir.
Por ejemplo:

```
archv = open('data1.py', 'w')
archv.write(" ")

def cod1():
    archv = open('data1.py', 'a')
    archv.write("from tkinter import *\n")
    archv.write("from tkinter import ttk\n")
    archv.write("window = Tk()\n")
    archv.write("\n")
    archv.write("\n")
    archv.write("\n")
    archv.write("\n")
    archv.write("window.mainloop()\n")
    archv.close()

def cod2():
    archv = open('data1.py', 'a')
    archv.write("botonc = ttk.Button(text='Cod1')\n")
    archv.write("botonc.place(x=0, y=0)\n")
```

En este código cuando llame a la función `cod1` se genera un código dentro del archivo `data.py` (que se crea en el principio del código).
Necesito que cuando llame a `cod2` se genere un código en el espacio blanco que hay en el código generado anteriormente.

Saludos y gracias desde ya por su ayuda .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código debería realizar lo que te propones en tiempo de ejecución o servirte de punto de partida para cumplir tus objetivos, además de pulir algunos detalles mejorables:

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

NOMBRE_FICHERO = 'data1.py'
LINEAS_COD2 = "botonc = ttk.Button(text='Cod2')\nbotonc.place(x=0, y=0)\n"


def escribir_fichero(contents):
    with open(NOMBRE_FICHERO, 'a') as f:
        f.write(contents)


def vaciar_fichero():
    with open(NOMBRE_FICHERO, 'w') as f:
        f.write("")


def cod1():
    vaciar_fichero()
    escribir_fichero("from tkinter import *\n")
    escribir_fichero("from tkinter import ttk\n")
    escribir_fichero("window = Tk()\n")
    escribir_fichero("\n")  # Espacio para inserción de código en runtime
    escribir_fichero("\n")
    escribir_fichero("window.mainloop()\n")


def cod2():
    with open(NOMBRE_FICHERO, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines.insert(-3, "\n")
    lines.insert(-3, LINEAS_COD2)
    with open(NOMBRE_FICHERO, 'w') as f:
        f.write("".join(lines))


def crear_boton(text, command, x, y):
    button = ttk.Button(text=text, command=command)
    button.place(x=x, y=y)


def main():
    vaciar_fichero()
    crear_boton("Cod1", cod1, 65, 0)
    crear_boton("Cod2", cod2, 65, 40)
    crear_boton("Borrar", vaciar_fichero, 65, 80)
    mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

He añadido las variables `NOMBRE_FICHERO` y `LINEAS_COD2` para evitar los típicos accidentes con valores *hardcodeados*. Además, he refactorizado `borrar()` transformándola en la función `vaciar_fichero()` y extraído la lógica de escribir en el fichero y de creación de botones en sendas funciones *ad hoc* `escribir_fichero()` y `crear_boton()` para mejorar la claridad y evitar la repetición del código.

Asimismo, he empleado la sentencia WITH para asegurar el cierre automático de recursos —incluso si el programa se cierra con excepciones— para un trabajo más seguro con ficheros que te ayudará a evitar problemas como el de la corrupción del contenido de data.py al que hacías referencia.

Por último, La función `cod2()` refactorizada ahora realiza una lectura del contenido del fichero, inserta las líneas de código especificadas en la variable `LINEAS_COD2` en el lugar deseado y escribe el nuevo contenido en el fichero.

Comment: En este caso no parece ser un problema, pero si el archivo tuviera miles de líneas, sería muy costoso a nivel de memoria llamar a `readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

El código que propongo buscará en el archivo original la primera línea en blanco de tu archivo.
Escribirá el texto que haya que añadir en medio de las líneas en blanco consecutivas que tenga tu archivo.

La respuesta cambia un poco si puedes permitirte tener todo el contenido del archivo en memoria o no.
En tu caso no parece que sea un problema; pero si tus archivos tuvieran miles de líneas llamar a `readlines()` y conservar esa lista de strings, sería muy costoso.

### Archivos pequeños

Abriremos el archivo en modo lectura.
Guardaremos todo su contenido en una lista.
Buscaremos la primera línea que esté vacía.
Escribiremos lo que sea menester en el medio de ese espacio vacío.
Usaremos la librería `pathlib` para trabajar con la ruta de los archivos.

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby

file_path = Path("data1.py")
# Guardo todo el archivo en memoria
with open(file_path, 'r') as archv:
    contenido = archv.readlines()
# Abro de nuevo el archivo en modo escritura
with open(file_path, 'w') as archv:
    # Agrupo las líneas que están vacías
    line_group = groupby(contenido, lambda line: line == '\n')
    # Si el archivo de origen empieza por una línea no vacía,
    # escribo las líneas no vacías en el archivo de destino
    inicio_archivo = next(line_group)
    if inicio_archivo[0] == False:
        archv.writelines(inicio_archivo[1])
        # Guardo un iterable de la primera tanda de líneas vacías
        espacio_blanco = next(line_group)
    else:
        espacio_blanco = inicio_archivo

    # Convierto el iterable a lista, así puedo preguntar su 'len'
    lineas_blancas = list(espacio_blanco[1])
    # Escribo la primera mitad de las líneas vacías
    archv.writelines(lineas_blancas[:len(lineas_blancas)//2])

    # Escribo el texto que sea menester
    archv.write("botonc = ttk.Button(text='Cod1')\n")
    archv.write("botonc.place(x=0, y=0)\n")

    # Escribo la segunda mitad de las líneas vacías
    archv.writelines(lineas_blancas[len(lineas_blancas)//2:])

    # Escribo el resto de las líneas del archivo origen
    for goup_lines in line_group:
        archv.writelines(goup_lines[1])
```

### Archivos grandes

Si el archivo original es demasiado grande necesitaremos un iterador para poder movernos por él: un iterador que no sea una lista.
Según avanzamos por el archivo de origen, escribiremos el archivo de destino.
El archivo de destino será un archivo nuevo al cual llamaremos con el sufijo `tmp`, de temporal.
Cuando hayamos terminado de escribir el nuevo archivo, le cambiaremos el nombre para que sustituya al antiguo.

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby, tee, islice

# Creo un path al un archivo temporal
file_path_tmp = file_path.with_stem(f"{file_path.stem}_tmp")
# Abro ambos archivos
with open(file_path, 'r') as archv_src, open(file_path_tmp, 'w') as archv_des:
    # Agrupo las líneas del archivo original
    line_group = groupby(archv_src, lambda line: line == '\n')
    inicio_archivo = next(line_group)
    if inicio_archivo[0] == False:
        archv_des.writelines(inicio_archivo[1])
        espacio_blanco = next(line_group)
    else:
        espacio_blanco = inicio_archivo

    # Como no puedo permitirme guardar en memoria las líneas en blanco,
    # utilizo dos iteradores
    it_lineas_blancas, lineas_blancas = tee(espacio_blanco[1], 2)
    # el primero lo consumo para contar cuántas líneas hay
    longitud_lineas_blancas = sum(1 for _ in it_lineas_blancas)
    # El segundo lo utilizo para escribir
    # la primera mitad en el archivo de destino
    archv_des.writelines(islice(lineas_blancas, longitud_lineas_blancas//2))

    # Escribo el texto que sea menester
    archv_des.write("botonc = ttk.Button(text='Cod1')\n")
    archv_des.write("botonc.place(x=0, y=0)\n")

    # Escribo la segunda tanda de líneas en blanco
    archv_des.writelines(lineas_blancas)

    # Escribo el resto del archivo
    for goup_lines in line_group:
        archv_des.writelines(goup_lines[1])

# Una vez que ambos archivos están cerrados,
# renombro el archivo de destino con el nombre original
file_path_tmp.replace(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma más optimizada para archivos grandes (aunque no la más simple) se puede lograr usando el cursor del objeto de archivo y un archivo temporal, reescribiendo solo la parte que realmente es necesario reescribir.

Pero antes del código, es importante saber...

#### Que es un cursor?

Un cursor en los objetos de archivo se parece mucho conceptualmente al cursor de los editores de texto, como el Bloc de Notas o Word (es decir, aquella barrita que nos indica donde será colocado el texto cuando lo escribamos).

El cursor en Python guarda una posición absoluta (que es el número de caracteres desde el inicio del archivo o número de bytes en caso que sea un archivo binario) e indica a los métodos read y write desde donde leer y escribir respectivamente. Ambos métodos mueven al cursor.

Podemos consultar y establecer la posición de esta excelente caracteristica usando los métodos tell y seek respectivamente.

#### Código

Como Python solo nos permite añadir texto si el cursor está al final del archivo (intentos de mover el cursor hacia atrás y escribir resultan en sobreescribir el texto anterior), no nos queda de otra que seguir este procedimiento:

- Copiar a un archivo temporal o a la memoria (si la parte no es grande) el contenido luego del cursor.
- volvemos a poner el cursor donde estaba y escribimos el nuevo texto, escribiendo "encima" del contenido anterior (el texto anterior se sobreeescribe con el nuevo)
- leer el archivo temporal y volcarlo, sobreescribiendo nuevamente el texto anterior.
- Como el nuevo contenido del archivo mide más que el contenido anterior, no hay necesidad de truncar o borrar el contenido del archivo, ya que fue sobreescrito todo el contenido de dicho.

A continuación, te dejo el código que se me ocurrió:

```
original_pos = file.tell()

if original_pos == file.seek(0, 2):
    file.write(text)
else:
    file.seek(original_pos)

    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size_in_memory, "w+") as temp:
        temp.writelines(file)
        temp.seek(0)

        file.seek(original_pos)
        
        file.write(text)

        pos = file.tell()

        file.writelines(temp)

    file.seek(pos)
```

**Explicación**

Creo que es conveniente explicar, linea por linea, que hace este código

- `original_pos = file.tell()` guardamos la posición del cursor en el momento de llamada la función en una variable. Esto debido a que moveremos el cursor a muchos lugares para luego devolverlo a su posición original.
- `if original_pos == file.seek(0, 2)` si la posición original es igual al final del archivo. file.seek(0, 2) significa "desde el final del archivo (2) moverse 0 caracteres y devolver la nueva posición absoluta".
  Esto es una forma de saber si el cursor estaba al final del archivo.

  - `file.write(text)` escribimos el texto en el archivo sin usar ningún truco. No necesitamos nada muy complejo para agregar texto al final del archivo. Esto optimiza considerablemente el proceso ya que no usa un archivo temporal ni llama inutilmente ciertos métodos.
- En caso contrario:

  - `file.seek(original_pos)` movemos el cursor a la posición original.
  - `with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size_in_memory, "w+") as temp:` esto, en resumen, actúa como un archivo, pero solo se crea realmente si el objeto supera cierto tamaño en memoria y se elimina cuando sale del with.
  - `temp.writelines(file)` la función writelines, escribe cada linea que recibe de file (el cual convierte en un iterador y lee cada linea desde la posición del cursor). Solo se carga en memoria una linea a la vez y, por supuesto, como tanto el iterador como el método están implementados en c, hay un plus de velocidad considerable.
    Esto mueve el cursor de cada archivo al final.
  - `temp.seek(0)` Movemos el cursor en el quizas archivo temporal al principio.
  - `file.seek(original_pos)` movemos el cursor a la posición original
  - `file.write(text)` escribimos el texto.
  - `pos = file.tell()` debido a que ahora nos toca agregar el contenido borrado (lo cual moverá el cursor), guardamos la posición actual del cursor en una variable. Esto nos permitirá imitar el comportamiento del método write y colocar el cursor justo donde el texto se agregó.
  - `file.writelines(temp)` recorremos todo el archivo temporal y escribimos cada linea en en archivo original.

**A tener en cuenta**

- Debido a que cada ejecución del código implica reescribir parte o todo el archivo y crear un archivo temporal, cuantas menos llamadas a esta función se realizen, mejor. Incluso, puede ser modificada ligeramente para que escriba varias lineas en el archivo "de una" cambiando `file.write(text)` a `file.writelines(textlist)`.
- Como este código lee lineas enteras, este proceso dará un error de memoria para lineas excesivamente largas (hablo de millones de caracteres). Sin embargo, elegí hacelo así por rendimiento (los bucles de python son más lentos que los de c y el iterador de lineas y el método writelines están implementados en c) y por que no es habitual tener lineas largas.
  Recomiendo no crear iteradores propios (excepto si se implementan en c) para leer x cantidad de caracteres en lugar de lineas. Esto debido a que afectará negativamente la velocidad.
- A pesar de la optimización, este código no se debería usar para casos donde siempre se escribe texto al final del archivo debido a que verifica si el cursor estaba en el final, cosa que demorará la escritura.